# Migrating metadata from sandbox to developer org using Mavens Mate

Tags: force.com, migration-tool, mavensmate, sublime

I've been trying to migrate the metadata including custom objects from a sandbox org to a free dev org.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 and Mavens Mate.

- I've downloaded the sandbox org metadata from github
- I've created a Mavensmate project from Sublime (Using create project from existing files)
- I've configured the deploy connection to point to my dev org
- I click on Deploy to server, don't get any errors

After that I go to my dev org and see if the custom objects were deployed but it's still empty.

Am I missing something?

I'm using:
- MavensMate 0.0.10
- Sublime Text 3

I've also tried using the data migration tool, but everytime I run ant I get this

BUILD FAILED
Target "test" does not exist in the project "Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks".

Comment: I assume you have a package since you tried the Ant based data migration tool. Have you tried deploying that package via [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) or (Shameless self promotion) the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/09/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-33162747.html).

Comment: @DanielBallinger That's correct, I have a package and also tried via MavensMate. I haven't tried either of your suggestions, kind of new to salesforce so first time I hear about them. I'll give them a try and let you know, thanks.